# Date Customization in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

How do I format/customize the `Date` class in Rails?

In my view, I want it to display `Thursday, February 18, 2016`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [i18](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html) style like this:

```
l @object.date, format: "%A, %B %d, %Y" if @object.date
```

That will give you the date in the format you want:

> Thursday, February 18, 2016

The good thing about that method, is it will translate to any language you might have the app on, for example, in spanish the date format would be:

> Jueves, Febrero 18, 2016

Without having to translate yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Use [strftime](http://apidock.com/ruby/DateTime/strftime)

In your case it would be something like this:

`somedate.strftime("%A, %B %d, %Y")`

Answer (score 1):

The neatest way I know is to use the [`to_formatted_s` (aliased as `to_s`) method](http://devdocs.io/rails/date#method-i-to_formatted_s) on `Date`, you can configure it with a date format like so:

```
Date::DATE_FORMATS[:yours] = "%A, %B %d, %Y"
```

Which you can then use on any `Date` instance like so:

```
Date.today.to_s :yours
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer is `I18n.l Time.now, format: "%A, %B %d, %Y"`